# Does the OP of a bounty get emailed once time is expired?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

Does the OP of a bounty question get emailed when the time is up? If not, can we make that a default option? You could make it an opt-out feature, but turned on to begin with.

Comment: Yep, that already happens.

Comment: Not only when it expires, but *as it's close* to expiring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the user who placed the bounty on a question does get emailed. From what I see in my own records, there are two emails:

- One stating that the bound will end soon (within a day).
- One stating that the grace periods has started (i.e. the day after the bounty has officially ended, when you can still award it).

Besides that there is a general notification on the website itself 3 days before the bounty is about to expire.

Should the user not return then you can still get half the bounty if you qualify for it. This is explained in ["How does the bounty system work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

> The criteria for an answer to be eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
> - The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter